# compiler error in Visual Studio when std::reduce is invoked for different iterator and init types

Tags: c++, c++20, reduce

Please consider the follownig simple code snippet:

```
template<typename T>
struct point2{ T x, y; };

template<typename T>
std::complex<T> foo(std::vector<point2<T>> const& x)
{
    std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, x.begin(), x.end(), std::complex<T>{},
        [&](std::complex<T> const& first, point2<T> const& second) {
            return first + std::complex<T>{ second.x, second.y };
        });
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2022 (with C++-Language set to C++20), I'm receiving the error message

> 'int foo::<lambda_1>::operator ()(const std::complex &,const
> point2 &) const': cannot convert argument 2 from
> 'std::complex' to 'const point2 &'

What is going wrong here? It seems like the type to which the iterators in the definition of `std::reduce` point to need to be the same as the chosen init value. But this doesn't seem to be a requirement described in the C++ standard. Am I missing something?

Comment: The answer quotes the standard, but I think it is fairly obvious that the lambda must be able to accept two `std::complex<T>` as arguments as well. How else would the parallel operations work? The individual per-thread results need to be merged at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) allows elements in the set to be grouped and rearranged in any order to allow for more efficient implementations. It is required that all combinations of `*first` and `init` are valid arguments to the `binary_op` (quote from [27.10.4 Reduce #5](https://eel.is/c++draft/reduce#5)):

> Mandates: All of
>
> ```
> binary_­op(init, *first),
> binary_­op(*first, init),
> binary_­op(init, init), and
> binary_­op(*first, *first)
> ```
>
> are convertible to T.

You seem to be looking for [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), which has the same effects, but ensures that order of evaluation is kept.

---

To keep possibility of using `std::execution::par_unseq`, you may try to add conversions between `point2` and `std::complex`:

```
template<typename T>
struct point2{ 
    T x, y; 
    point2(const std::complex<T>& c): x{c.real()}, y{c.imag()} {}

    // Or replace first argument in lambda with point2<T>
    // instead of this conversion operator, and adjust the rest accordingly
    operator std::complex<T>() { return {x, y};}
};
```

Altough I'm not sure if the conversions won't take away the benefit of parallelizing the algorithm, you should test and profile both versions before using them.

Comment: Since OP is using `std::execution::par_unseq` they probably _do_ want the `std::reduce` behavior. `std::accumulate` can't be parallelized.

Comment: @user17732522 Ah, didn't notice that. Let me edit with another solution.